# Content of Build and Devel folder of any package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, cmake

I have a basic question regarding the content of Build and Devel folder of any package in of Linux. What does each of this folder actually contain? Also am I supposed to delete both these folder if I want to make these packages from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**build folder**: This folder contains all object files / artifacts 
**devel folder**: (Short for development) is where built targets are placed prior to being installed. 
 This is usefull for testing for example. 
**install folder**: After running the install command this is where the final targets will be placed.

Comment: So will I need to delete only build folder if I have to make all the packages form scratch?